# How work with statements in meteor template

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I like to work with meteor, but I have a problem I can't find a solution for.

In the template file I have this code:

```
<template name="klussenboard">
<h2>Klussen</h2>
  <div class="klussenboard">
     {{#each klus}}
    {{#if status=1}}
    <li>
    <a class="startlink" href="#"><img src="/images/starten.png"></a>
    </li>
    {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
</template>
```

This is the js client code

```
Template.klussenboard.klus = function () {
        return Klussen.find({"status": { $gt: 0 }}, {
        sort: {datum: -1}
    });
};
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do a statement in a template file?

Looking forward to an answer.

Comment: Is this your whole template? Can you post any client side code that would be populating your template?

Answer (score 3):

Spacebars (meteor's templating library), much like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (that it is based on) doesn't execute arbitrary expressions like, say, angular.js's templates.

If you change the statement you're trying to write into a helper method, like so (feel free to pick a better name!):

```
<template name="klussenboard">
  <h2>Klussen</h2>
  <div class="klussenboard">
    {{#each klus}}
      {{#if isEnabled}}
        <li>
          <a class="startlink" href="#"><img src="/images/starten.png"></a>
        </li>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

You could then define the isEnabled helper in any client side .js file - say, `client/klussenboard.js` like so:

```
Template.item.isEnabled = function() {
  return this.status == 1;
}
```

So, `this`, in helper functions is

This assumes that you are in a context where `status` is a variable (which, based on your question, you are)

This would then reactively update whenever the `status` variable changes.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that angular.js's templates don't execute raw javascript either, but they do execute javascript-_like_ statements - i just used it as an example of a js templating library that _does_ allow inline statements.

Comment: You are a hero. Thanks!!